# How do I create a double SYN packet?

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I am doing allot of network developing and I am starting a new research.
I need to send a packet which will then cause another SYN packet to be sent.
This is how I want it to look:

I send syn -->  --> sends another SYN before SYN/ACK packet.

How can I cause?

I am using Scapy + Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. Is there any difference between your two SYN packets? If so, just create two SYN as you want and then send them together. If not, send same packets twice using `scapy.send(pkt, 2)`.I don't remember the specific parameters, but I'm sure scapy.send can send as many packets and fast as you like.

Comment: I see the confusion. I do not want my PC to send the SYN packet from command. I want a error in the connection causing a SYN packet to be sent again.

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you want to simulate TCP retransmition?

Comment: I think you need to use TCP fast retransmition mechanism. Send out first SYN from source, then send 4 same ACK to source in order to make source to send SYN again. With Thread and scapy, you can achieve this.